# Dynamic response status in Express async/await error handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to replace promises chain inside my Express routing with async/await. This makes code clean and more readable. First look at my code.

What i've had before:

```
app.post('/search', (req,res) => {
    sendRequest(req.body).then( searchDetails => {
        res.send(searchDetails);
    }).catch( error => {
        res.status(404).send(error)
    });
});
```

Current code:

```
app.post('/search', asyncMiddleware(async (req,res) => {
    const result = await sendRequest(req.body);
    res.send(result);
}));
```

And this how looks asyncMiddleware:

```
const asyncMiddleware = checkedFunction => (req, res) => {
    Promise
        .resolve(
            checkedFunction(req, res)
        )
        .catch( error => {
            res.status(400).send(error)
        });
};
```

The problem starts when I have routing which includes more than one error status.

```
app.delete('/delete/:id', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }

    User.findOneAndDelete({
        _id: id,
        _user: req.user._id
    }).then((todo) => {
      if (!todo) {
        return res.status(404).send();
      }

      res.send({todo});
    }).catch((e) => {
      res.status(400).send();
    });
});
```

How can I make to asyncMiddleware will return status depends on error?

Answer (score 1):

`asyncMiddleware` here checks if any error has occured or is deliberately thrown by `checkedFunction`, namely express route handler. If you would like to say something to `asyncMiddleware`, you need to wrap your route handler with it as you did for `/search`, then you need to throw specific errors/objects involving your error information:

```
app.delete('/delete/:id', authenticate, asyncMiddleware(async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
      throw {
          status: 404,
          message: 'id not valid'
      }
    }

    try {
        const todo = await User.findOneAndDelete({
            _id: id,
            _user: req.user._id
        });

        if (!todo) {
            throw {
                status: 404,
                message: 'todo not found'
            }
        }
        res.send({todo});
    } catch (e) {
        throw {
            status: 400,
            message: 'mongodb error'
        }
    }
}));
```

then asyncMiddleware can send status in response

```
const asyncMiddleware = checkedFunction => (req, res) => {
    Promise
        .resolve(
            checkedFunction(req, res)
        )
        .catch( error => {
            res.status(error.status).send(error.message)
        });
};
```

You can create built-in `Error` objects instead of custom ones to track error call stack but I don't think you need here.